# When can I replace g or th with '?

Tags: word-usage, elision

I am reading Heidi Grant Halvorson's book [Succeed: How We Can Reach Our Goals](https://www.authentichappiness.sas.upenn.edu/de/content/succeed-how-we-can-reach-our-goals-heidi-grant-halvorson-phd) but assailed by these two chapter titles: `How to Keep On Keepin' On` and `Know When to Fold 'Em`.

I thought they can also be written as How to `Keep On Keeping On` and `Know When to Fold Them`, and I have encountered such spelling several times elsewhere.

When can I spell that way?

Comment: It's informal writing. In this case, almost slang—but certainly colloquial. In general, you can replace the *g* in any verb with an apostrophe. If you want to write in this style, that is. Don't do it in formal writing.

Comment: @JasonBassford But why someone write that way? Do they just get used to it or it would be more convenient or seem more native?

Comment: People write (and talk) differently in different contexts.

Comment: This speech pattern is called *dropping g's*.  You can read much more about it on English.SE: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42386/what-kind-of-human-character-or-regional-trait-does-the-habit-of-the-g-dropping

Comment: For the specific phrase *keep on keeping on*, many people are most familiar with it (directly or indirectly) from its appearance in Bob Dylan's song "Tangled Up In Blue", and Dylan drops the *g* when he sings the word *keeping* (it's a common pattern in the way he sings).  You can hear it [here](https://youtu.be/YwSZvHqf9qM?t=181).

Comment: When you're talking about what letters a word is written with, the verb is *spell* instead of *type*.

Comment: @Anonymous Thanks for figuring it out, and I have updated my question. Please help check. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep**in** and keep**ing** are two variants of the same word. They mean the same thing.

Some dialects use *-ing* formally, and *-in* informally.

Some dialects have only one or the other.

Some dialects have both, with different meanings: *-in* makes a gerund/participle, but *-ing* makes a noun. (This distinction has been lost in most dialects.)

When you're learning English, you should always use *-ing*, because that's what the standard dialects do.

(*-in* is often spelled *-in'*, as if it were *-ing* with the G omitted, but that is not actually what happened; it never had a G.)

Comment: I have updated my question, could you please check it?

Comment: @LernerZhang: Yes, *'em* is a variant of *them* in some dialects.